# Why does it go through netfilter postrouting when visiting local ports?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter

Environment：

```
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
```

I have set log printing in the following chain：

```
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT SPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT SPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "POSTROUTING SPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "POSTROUTING DPORT 8000 LOGS: "
```

Then I execute the telnet command：

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8000
```

tail -f /var/log/message, show the following：

```
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: OUTPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6163 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: POSTROUTING DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6163 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: INPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6163 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: OUTPUT SPORT 8000 LOGS: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8000 DPT=51096 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: INPUT SPORT 8000 LOGS: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8000 DPT=51096 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: OUTPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6164 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: INPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6164 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Excuse me, when accessing locally, why does SYN packet go through POSTROUTING?

Subsequent ACK+SYN packets did not go through POSTROUTING, why?

May I ask why this is so, is there any information about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking schematic describing how packets are moved within the Linux network stack (you can ignore the lower blue link layer field, it's used for bridging rather than routing):

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

For a packet to stay local to the system, it will have to have be evaluated by the routing stack to use the `lo` (loopback) interface:

```
# ip route get 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo src 127.0.0.1 uid 0 
    cache <local>
```

So it will follow the flow described in the schematic

- emitted by a local process
- routing decision: output interface `lo`
- various chains hooking in OUTPUT
- various chains hooking in POSTROUTING: this always happens for forwarded or emitted packets
- finally emitted to the `lo` interface, at the right of the schematic

The `lo` interface now plays its role: loopback. The packet is looped back through the `lo` interface and arrives back at the left of the schematic... again to the `lo` interface but this time as incoming, not as outgoing.

- incoming packet "from" the `lo` interface
- various chains hooking in PREROUTING: this always happens for received packets
- routing decision: destination will be a local process
- various chains hooking in INPUT
- received by a local process

Now there's a catch: NAT. A NAT rule is here to establish how will all other packets in the same flow be transformed in the same way. Once NAT happens for a given flow, every other packet of the same flow, including the replies, will be handled directly by Netfilter and conntrack (which memorizes the needed information about this flow, including how NAT was done): they won't traverse *iptables* anymore. In the schematic there's a note about it:

> "nat" table only consulted for "NEW" connections

Everything else about NAT for this flow is then short-circuited by Netfilter which won't call *iptables* nat hooks anymore.

---

This allows to explain the results using the nat table. With the two nat/POSTROUTING rules:

- the very first packet of the flow: the initial query (a SYN packet)  will traverse the NAT rules

  - The `--dport` filter matches and triggers a log
  - The `--sport` doesn't match (no log)
- any following packet of the flow, including the reply from the application from port 8080 won't traverse the nat table anymore, because the flow already exists (ie: the packet is not in "NEW" state)

  so in the end the `--sport` rule will never log anything.

Likewise, should a LOG rule be also added in nat/PREROUTING (or in the rarely used nat/INPUT), it won't display anything coming from the `lo` interface, because the first packet of a local flow is always emitted *to* `lo` before being received *from* `lo`: such flow will always already exist.

If instead you were logging in mangle/POSTROUTING with:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "mangle POSTROUTING SPORT 8000 LOGS: "
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "mangle POSTROUTING DPORT 8000 LOGS: "
```

you would see each query and each reply packets in the logs, just like filter/INPUT and filter/OUTPUT.

If instead of above a filter to see only packets in NEW state is also added, just like always happens for the *nat* table:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -p tcp --sport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "mangle POSTROUTING SPORT 8000 LOGS: "
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -p tcp --dport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "mangle POSTROUTING DPORT 8000 LOGS: "
```

then again the same initial behavior would happen: only one log for the first packet for each flow (and thus never for `--sport` because it's a reply, so not the first packet of the flow).